# How to plot a CSV with coordinates one row at a time via Geopandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, geopandas, shapely

I have a CSV of all earthquakes in my country for the last 10 years arranged by date and time. **My goal is to plot each line chronologically one by one** so that I can compile these maps and produce a "time-lapse" of the earthquakes. The CSV is already sorted but I'll code the "sorting" function when I get there.

So if I have 10 earthquakes, the end products are 10 maps with each a single plot of where the earthquake happened.

My code:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
import geopandas as gpd
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame
import pandas as pd
import os

os.chdir(r'path')

def plotPoint():
    df = pd.read_csv('earthquakes.csv')
    geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df['Longitude'], df['Latitude'])]
    crs = "epsg:32651"
    gdf = GeoDataFrame(df, crs=crs, geometry=geometry)
    basemap = gpd.read_file('basemap.shp')
    for i in range(len(gdf)): # Counts how many rows there are then loops through each line of "gdf"
        if i == 0: # Skips over first line since it is the column header
            continue
        pt = gdf.plot(ax=basemap.plot(figsize=(10,6)), marker='o', color='red', markersize=15)
        print(pt[i]) # Executes "pt" one line at a time
plotPoint()
```

When I run this, I get

```
File "C:\path\file.py", line 26, in plotPoint
    print(pt[i]) 
TypeError: 'AxesSubplot' object is not subscriptable
```

I'm still new to Python. Any leads?

Comment: The plot function returns an "AxesSubplot" object, which you cannot slice with `[1]`

Comment: at each iteration of the for loop you are creating the same plot, since gdf does not change